# Why can't I copy-initialize a stringstream from a string?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, copy-initialization

The following code fails in GCC, Clang and Visual Studio:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "hello"; // ok, copy-initialization
    std::stringstream ss1(s); // ok, direct-initialization
    std::stringstream ss2 = s; // error
}
```

I thought the only case where direct-initialization works while copy-initialization doesn't is when the constructor is explicit, which it is not in this case. What's going on?

Comment: Codepad example: http://codepad.org/du90Fkck

Comment: I'm confused with why you're trying to set a std::stringstream to a string. There is no default assignment operator for this. Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/operator=/).

Comment: @Dan that's initialization, not assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That constructor *is* marked explicit, so can only be used with direct-initialization. §27.8.5:

```
explicit basic_stringstream(
ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::out | ios_base::in);

explicit basic_stringstream(
const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& str,
ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::out | ios_base::in);

basic_stringstream(const basic_stringstream& rhs) = delete;

basic_stringstream(basic_stringstream&& rhs);
```

(The same is true for `basic_stringbuf`, `basic_istringstream`, and `basic_ostringstream`.)

Comment: But that's stringbuf, not stringstream.

Comment: @Nikolai: Whoops, good eye. At least 5 other people missed that too. :) Updated the text, it is the case that constructor is explicit for all string-stream related types.

Comment: I see, there was an error on cppreference.com. I've fixed it.